# How can I traverse React Component Tree just using __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__

Tags: reactjs, browser, google-chrome-devtools, react-devtools

I am trying to traverse through React Component Tree( or somehow get access to all components)
and create my own custom UI inside the browser(most likely an extension) to manipulate different components.

this is my code:

```
// const root_node = root._internalRoot.current; 
const root_node = document.getElementById('root')
const renderer = window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.get(1);
const rendered_root_node = renderer.findFiberByHostInstance(root_node);
```

But it's returning null. I tried using findHostInstanceByFiber as well.

Is there any way to traverse through the components in the browser?

Comment: Inspect the source code of *React devtools extension* which shows how to setup this HOOK thing. This is required to receive the info from React, AFAICT.

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser or https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how you can traverse the React component tree using the `renderers` property of the `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` object:

```js
function traverseComponentTree(renderer, fiberNode, callback) {
    callback(fiberNode);
  
    let child = fiberNode.child;
    while (child) {
        traverseComponentTree(renderer, child, callback);
        child = child.sibling;
    }
}

const renderer = window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.renderers.get(1);
const rootFiber = renderer.mounts[0];

traverseComponentTree(renderer, rootFiber, (fiberNode) => {
  console.log(fiberNode.stateNode); // this will give you the instance of the component
  console.log(fiberNode.type); // this will give you the type of the component
});
```

Please keep in mind that this code is intended for development use only, as the `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` is not available in production mode.

Also, If you are using the latest version of react, it's important to know that the `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` has been removed.

Comment: This doesn't produce any output for me. I just get `Set(0) {size: 0}`

Comment: The `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` is typically initialized by the React DevTools browser extension (so it is available for development and production builds, so long as that extension is installed). Something _could_ define this interface (fast refresh does for example) but it's not recommended, since it could break official tools, and the APIs it uses aren't meant to be publicly consumed.